# What are the possible region codes in the Amadeus API?

Tags: iso, region, amadeus

I am working with the Airline Routes endpoint (`/airline/destinations`) of the Amadeus Self-Service API and want to figure out what the possible values for the regionCode property are to be able to filter airports by region. The [API documentation](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/flights/api-doc/airline-routes/api-reference) tells me that the regionCode is the "code of the region of the location in ISO standard" but neither can I find any ISO standard for regions nor a list of the possible values this property might have.

Does anyone know either the ISO standard the documentation talks about or if there's a public list of region codes?

Through testing I could find most of the values ("EUROP","NAMER","ASIA","EURAS","SEASI","SAMER","AUSTL","MEAST","CARIB") but I would like to have some certainty on which regions there are and what countries they correspond to.

My last resort would be to ask the Amadeus support, but this is not an option for me right at this minute, unfortunately.